# WordPress Subscribe email Form

Tags: php, wordpress, email, web

I am pretty new to WordPress and one of my friends requested me to make two subscribe email forms in his new business website.

In WordPress, I used the plug-in called "Contact Form to Email."

The first subscribe email form (in the footer), I made it with default Contact Form to Email plug-in and applied the style with editing HTML and CSS code.

The second subscribe email form (in the header,) I made the form completely by myself with HTML and CSS. (That means that this "subscribe" does not have any function yet. Does not work when user fill out email and click Subscribe button)

I want to know the code that I need to use to make header subscription have same function as footer subscription.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/visual-form-builder/ - great form plugin for wordpress - you can make countless forms -> very easy and user friendly solution.... and there are tones of similar plugins....

Comment: You need to write PHP code for that.

Answer (score 1):

On the same page, write PHP code like below:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])):

    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $wpdb->insert( 'table-name', 
    array(
    'firstname' => $firstName , 
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    ),
    array(
    '%s', '%s',
    )
    );

    endif;
    ?>
```

change the variable and table name as per your coding.